# Parse JSON with PERL

Tags: json, perl, parsing

I'd like to parse a JSON string with PERL.
My JSON string;

```
{"to_id": 0, "message": "This is a sample", "message_id": 1000, "from_id": 999}
```

How to parse the JSON and return all objects and values.
Sample output;

```
to_id: 0
message: This is a sample
message_id: 1000
from_id: 999
```

No XML output and object and value in separate variables
Thanks in advance

Comment: Even though the other question is oriented towards XML output, the answer with more votes is useful. Is basically the same as @TLP answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) module. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $str = q|{"to_id": 0, "message": "This is a sample", "message_id": 1000, "from_id": 999}|;

print Dumper from_json($str);
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'from_id' => 999,
          'message_id' => 1000,
          'to_id' => 0,
          'message' => 'This is a sample'
        };
```

Comment: @Robertico So put them in different variables. If you have problems with basic perl data structures, perhaps you should consult some of the documentation.

Comment: @Robertico I showed you how to parse JSON, that was your question. If you want me to write the entire program for you, I'm going to have to charge you for my time.

Comment: @Robertico, `for my $key (keys %$hash) { my $val = $hash->{$key}; ... }`